# how to refresh jstl test using ajax of primefaces?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces, jstl

for example: when I click on the button `A`. I get the  following text : `you have choosed A`.

But when I change button, I get the same text, although the value of `#{bean.str}` changes

Here is my code :

```
<p:selectOneButton id="selectId" value="#{bean.str}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="A" itemValue="1" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="B" itemValue="2" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="C" itemValue="3" />
            <f:ajax event="change" render="tabView" listener="#{bean.change}" />
</p:selectOneButton>

<c:if var="test" test="#{bean.str =='1'}">
        <h:outputText value="you have choosed A" />
</c:if>
<c:if test="#{beanApplication.perspective=='2'}">
        <h:outputText value="you have choosed B" />
</c:if>
<c:if test="#{beanApplication.perspective=='3'}">
        <h:outputText value="you have choosed C" />
</c:if>
```

I am looking for a way to refresh the JSTL `<c:if>` test when I click on the button.

Comment: You forgot to obfuscate some `beanApplication.perspective` expressions, hereby introducing red herrings in your question. Please edit in the real code and test it and copypaste the real code (so, don't not edit in the question afterwards).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSTL runs during JSF view build time, not during JSF view render time. However, the submitted value is  in this particular example only set as bean property *after* view build time. The view build time runs during JSF RESTORE_VIEW phase, but the bean property is set during JSF UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES phase.

You need to evaluate the condition during render time instead. Use the therefor provided JSF component's `rendered` attribute.

```html
<h:outputText value="you have chosen A" rendered="#{bean.str == '1'}" />
<h:outputText value="you have chosen B" rendered="#{bean.str == '2'}" />
<h:outputText value="you have chosen C" rendered="#{bean.str == '3'}" />
```

Further, you should be using `<p:ajax>` in PrimeFaces components, not `<f:ajax>`. Also you should ensure that the component referenced as `tabView` in `<f:ajax render>` (and equivalently, the `<p:ajax update>`) covers the above three components. Here's a complete kickoff example:

```html
<p:selectOneButton id="selectId" value="#{bean.str}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="A" itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="B" itemValue="2" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="C" itemValue="3" />
    <p:ajax listener="#{bean.change}" update="tabView" />
</p:selectOneButton>

<h:panelGroup id="tabView">
    <h:outputText value="you have chosen A" rendered="#{bean.str == '1'}" />
    <h:outputText value="you have chosen B" rendered="#{bean.str == '2'}" />
    <h:outputText value="you have chosen C" rendered="#{bean.str == '3'}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: thank you for you response my friend !. I  tried your suggestion but I get the same result. now I tried to put all `<h:outputText` in `<h:panelGroup`, and then I render his id with `<f:ajax`, not with `<p:ajax`

Comment: You're welcome. The JSTL problem is indeed not immediately obvious to starters, but I'd expect that the mis-rendering problem would be obvious enough to starters (as this is clearly visible in ajax response).

Answer (score 1):

You can put all condition in a panel and re render on the button click

Comment: what is the panel component?

Comment: I think @BalusC has given panel component with example in the post and the component name is h:panelGroup

Answer (score 0):

use the attribute "rendered" on your 3 outputText