# Conditional rendering of two different h:commandButton actions

Tags: jsf, jstl, commandbutton, conditional-rendering, ajax-update

**Technology Used  :**

JSF 2

Primefaces

**Problem statement :**

We have one drop down list as below -

```
<h:selectOneMenu value ="#{bean.value}"> 
   <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.processValue}" 
    render="{one,two or panel}" />   //render correct id based on approach

   <f:selectItem itemValue = "1" itemLabel = "Item 1" /> 
   <f:selectItem itemValue = "2" itemLabel = "Item 2" />
   <f:selectItem itemValue = "3" itemLabel = "Item 3" /> 
   <f:selectItem itemValue = "4" itemLabel = "Item 4" /> 
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

If user selects item 2 , a button is displayed which when clicked opens up a pop up menu. 
If user selects item 1 or 3 or 4 , another button is displayed which triggers a business action when clicked.

We are able to get AJAX invocation for `h:selectOneMenu` using `f:ajax`.
We are using `render` attribute of `f:ajax`

This is working fine.

The question is how to design two buttons on AJAX response.

**Approach one without using JSTL :**

```
<h:commandButton id="one" value="Submit" onClick="openPopup" rendered="#{bean.render}">
<h:commandButton id="two" value="Submit" action="#{bean.businessAction}" rendered="#{bean.render}">
```

where `#{bean.render}` will check for value of item clicked and return true/false.

**Approach two with using JSTL :**

Wrap two buttons within same panelGrid and render only panelGrid. Use JSTL inside panelGrid to control rendering.

```
<h:panelGrid id="panel">
  <c:choose>     
     <c:when test = "${itemVlaue == 2}"> // use appropriate EL expression 
       <!-- render command button 1 to open pop up --> 
     </c:when>

     <c:when test = "${itemVlaue == 1 or 3 or 5  }"> // use appropriate EL expression 
       <!-- render command button 2 to invoke action --> 
     </c:when>
  </c:choose>
</h:panelGrid>
```

I have searched over internet and it seems approach one is more correct since it is not advisable to use JSTL inside JSF to control rendering.

But the question is then :

We end up creating two command buttons when only one is being used.

Also what if two command buttons need to have only one id . That is only one should be present at any point on time .

Please advice

Comment: Your question is genuinely confusing. The <f:ajax> tag was introduced only in JSF 2.0. But the problems when mixing JSTL with JSF is only applicable to JSF 1.x. Which JSF version are you really using?

Comment: @Balusc - My blunder. I have updated the question. We are using JSF2 only. The main point here is what is the best way to render components ? Using JSTL or JSF mechanisms. And repercussions of using JSF mechanism as mentioned in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Y-problem is answered in:

- [how to refresh jstl test using ajax of primefaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345212/how-to-refresh-jstl-test-using-ajax-of-primefaces/)
- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)
- [Ajax update/render does not work on a component which has rendered attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790014/ajax-update-render-does-not-work-on-a-component-which-has-rendered-attribute)

Your X-problem is answered as below:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.value}">
   ...
   <f:ajax listener="#{bean.processValue}" render="oneAndOnly" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
...
<h:commandButton id="oneAndOnly" value="Submit"
    onclick="#{bean.render ? 'openPopup();return false;' : ''}"
    action="#{bean.businessAction}">
</h:commandButton>
```

In other words, just let it conditionally render the onclick attribute itself which returns `false`.

Comment: Using same command button to open up pop up and call action is amazing . I could not think of it. Thanks a lot again